# Adding take off and landing into teleop_twist_keyboard.py

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully sourced and compiled so I can fly my bebop drone using the teleop_twist_keyboard python script.

However I am currently having to run a separate terminal to make the bebop land and take off. Can someone help with how to edit the python script so I can assign the keys 1 ans 2 to mean take off and land respectively.

I have tried various combinations none with any luck (in addition to the original teleop twist keyboard script)

```
def takeoff():
   pub = rospy.Publisher("bebop/takeoff", Empty, queue_size=10 )
   rospy.init_node('takeoff', anonymous=True)
   rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
       pub.publish(Empty())
       rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
       takeoff()
   except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
       pass

def land():
   pub = rospy.Publisher("ardrone/land", Empty, queue_size=10 )
   rospy.init_node('land', anonymous=True)
   rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
   while not rospy.is_shutdown():
       pub.publish(Empty())
       rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
       land()
   except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
       pass
1= takeoff()
2= land()
```

(didnt expect this one to work )Also tried:

```
moveBindings = {
        'i':(1,0,0,0),
        'o':(1,0,0,-1),
        'j':(0,0,0,1),
        'l':(0,0,0,-1),
        'u':(1,0,0,1),
        ',':(-1,0,0,0),
        '.':(-1,0,0,1),
        'm':(-1,0,0,-1),
        'O':(1,-1,0,0),
        'I':(1,0,0,0),
        'J':(0,1,0,0),
        'L':(0,-1,0,0),
        'U':(1,1,0,0),
        '<':(-1,0,0,0),
        '>':(-1,-1,0,0),
        'M':(-1,1,0,0),
        't':(0,0,1,0),
        'b':(0,0,-1,0),
        '1'= rostopic pub --once [namespace]/takeoff std_msgs/Empty,
        '2'= rostopic pub --once [namespace]/land std_msgs/Empty  }`enter code here`
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273938/adding-take-off-and-landing-into-teleop_twist_keyboard.py/) by [jfursdon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32295/jfursdon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-24**:
[This repo](https://github.com/mikehamer/ardrone_tutorials) isn't exactly what you're looking for (it's for the AR.Drone 2.0), but it may be helpful. Also, checkout [Mike Hamer's tutorial for the 2.0](http://robohub.org/up-and-flying-with-the-ar-drone-and-ros-getting-started/) as well.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-24**:
Also, you said

> I have tried various combinations

what are these exactly? Can you update your question with your attempts?

**Comment by [jfursdon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32295/jfursdon/) on 2017-10-24**:
Thanks for the link but these do not explain how to change a python script. They are relating to configuring a joystick which I am not using. Thanks though.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-24**:
There is a keyboard teleop node too. And as I asked earlier, can you please update your question with what you've tried.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-10-26**:
Thanks for the update, but in order to make the question readable please use the *Preformatted Text* (`1010101`) button to properly format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have made a couple of very simple modifications to the original script in order to achieve that. What I've done is the following. First, import the Empty message:

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('teleop_twist_keyboard')
import rospy

from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from std_msgs.msg import Empty
```

Then, create 2 new Publishers, one for landing and the other one for taking off. And create an instance of the Empty message:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
        settings = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
    
    pub = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size = 1)
    rospy.init_node('teleop_twist_keyboard')
    pub2 = rospy.Publisher('drone/takeoff', Empty, queue_size = 1)
    pub3 = rospy.Publisher('drone/land', Empty, queue_size = 1)
    empty_msg = Empty()
```

Finally, just add 2 conditions for the new keys:

```
while(1):
    key = getKey()
    if key in moveBindings.keys():
        x = moveBindings[key][0]    
        y = moveBindings[key][1]    
        z = moveBindings[key][2]    
        th = moveBindings[key][3]
    elif key in speedBindings.keys():   
        speed = speed * speedBindings[key][0]   
        turn = turn * speedBindings[key][1]

        print vels(speed,turn)  
        if (status == 14):
            print msg   
        status = (status + 1) % 15

    elif key == '1':
        pub2.publish(empty_msg)
    elif key == '2':
        pub3.publish(empty_msg)

    else:
        x = 0   
        y = 0   
        z = 0   
        th = 0  
        if (key == '\x03'):
            break

    twist = Twist()
twist.linear.x = x*speed; twist.linear.y = y*speed; twist.linear.z = z*speed;
twist.angular.x = 0; twist.angular.y = 0; twist.angular.z = th*turn
pub.publish(twist)
```

I have also created a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcMQX8Fcvfg) showing how to do it and testing the script. Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Alberto E.](https://answers.ros.org/users/31003/alberto-e./) with karma: 356 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jfursdon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32295/jfursdon/) on 2017-10-30**:
Thank you very much, it worked a treat. The video really helped allow me to understand what was being done and why.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: I think the suggestion by @jayess is actually a very good one: the repository he links you to contains a good example of a proper keyboard teleop / controller node that you could very likely use with your specific drone as well. See [mikehamer/ardrone_tutorials/src/keyboard_controller.py](https://github.com/mikehamer/ardrone_tutorials/blob/364ded09492218ce71be6d58efc431923bfb927d/src/keyboard_controller.py).

---

I believe your issue is that you're creating `Publisher` *inside* the callback function that handles your keypress. That is not going to work: setting up `Publisher`s and getting `Subscriber`s to notice them and subscribe to them is going to take some time.

You'll want to treat `Publisher`s and `Subscriber`s as persistent objects, that you *create once*, somewhere in the initialisation phase of your program, and then *use* inside your callback.

Second: *never* include any sort of blocking `while` inside a callback: callbacks like this are supposed to quickly process an event and then return. Including a loop of any kind will make that impossible, and may even block your entire program. With Python this is sometimes hard to detect / notice, as it may spawn `N` threads to process these things. In your case, that may lead to `N` instances of `Publisher`, all `publish`ing `Empty` msgs at 10 Hz to the `bebop/takeoff`, even after you've let go of the key.

My advise would be to structure your code similar to how `teleop_twist_key.py` is setup already, but making sure that the `Empty` msg gets published by your `Publisher` when the key you'd like to use is pressed. You'll have to make sure that the code doesn't get to [this section](https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard/blob/479bdfb3ca0d16e8650f074053a44acf95432ddc/teleop_twist_keyboard.py#L116-L119) if your keys are pressed, because otherwise it will also `publish` a `Twist` msg, which is probably not what you want (or it could be, if you'd like to exploit the "publish all-zeros `Twist` if I haven't pressed any key" behaviour).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jfursdon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32295/jfursdon/) on 2017-10-30**:
Thanks very much for the explanation. Helped a lot